# AT-CIPSEND Number of Characters SIM Tech GSM modules

Tags: arduino, gsm, tcp-ip

I am succeeding in sending an update string via a SIM800L to ThingSpeak but the channel is not updating the channel.  I know the string is correct since it is provided by the site that I am posting to.

I have read on this site that the string length needs to be defined to be 4 more than the character count.  Does this always work?

Where would one find instructions regarding correct use the AT-CIPSEND command with SIM Tech devices?

I using an Arduino Pro Mini and interfacing with the modem using a Software Serial connection.

Comment: Need more clarifications and explanations on what is your whole setup

Comment: The secret is that the request string needs to be terminated with a double carriage return and line feed.

Answer (score 1):

The string needs to be terminated with a carriage return and newline and then followed by a further carriage return and newline. I now use println("GET /update?...." )  for the request string and follow it with a final println().